# Sequelize associations using hasOne and belongsTo

Tags: node.js, associations, sequelize.js

In sequelize when deleting using destroy() method with a table having associations with another table the entery associated with the parent table from the database is correctly deleted but I am still getting this error  "Error dropping database: Error: ER_ROW_IS_REFERENCED: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Address association model is defined as follows:

```
classMethods: {
    associate: function (models){
       Address.belongsTo(models.User);
    }
}
```

User association model is defined as follows:

```
classMethods: {
   associate: function (models){
      User.hasOne(models.Address, {onDelete: 'cascade'});
   }
}
```

Any help on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this.

```
Address.belongsTo(models.User, {
    foreignKeyConstraint: true
    , onDelete: 'cascade'
});
```